# u-boot don't continue if tftp fails

Tags: u-boot

I have u-boot configured to load two images: first it loads an FPGA bitfile (top.bit) using tftp, and then it loads the linux image using "netboot" which gets image.ub using tftp. Here is my bootcmd:

```
run uenvboot; tftpboot 0x4000000 192.168.0.55:top.bit; fpga loadb 0 0x4000000 0x1fcbff; run cp_kernel2ram && bootm 0x10000000; run netboot
```

This works when both files exist and the server is ready. However, if top.bit doesn't exist, I get:

```
TFTP error: 'File not found' (1)
Not retrying...
```

Is there an option to have u-boot not continue if the first top.bit load fails?

For the record, I do have netretry set to yes.

Comment: There is no option to get U-Boot to ignore/retry such a fatal error condition.  Such errors do not fix themselves after a retry.  You could however write a script to handle/ignore the error.

Comment: My goal is not to retry until the errors "fix themselves", but to safely exit and not continue to boot the system. I was unaware that you can create scripts in u-boot. Do you have an example?

Comment: I figured it out. I could use the "itest" command with a simple if/then/else structure. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use boolean operators, e.g.

```
true && echo true
false || echo false
```